# Mounting samba share in using fstab

Tags: 12.10, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I tried to mount a samba share from the local network to a folder in my PC. I added the following line in `fstab`

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.5/my/folder/ /home/mounts/localmount/
```

But when I do `sudo mount -a`, it gives the following error:-

```
[mntent]: line 13 in /etc/fstab is bad
```

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? I'm on Ubuntu 12.10, so `sudo smbmount //hostname/sharename ~/mounts/sharename -o user=username` wont work [[source]](https://askubuntu.com/a/84496/21561)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entry in fstab is not a command; don't include the `sudo mount` portion.

Instead, make the line look something like

```
//192.168.1.5/my/folder /home/mounts/localmount cifs rw
```

A [similar thread over at UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1658828) has more good information about further options, if you need login credentials, special encoding, or other permissions settings.

Comment: Thanks :) I added the following line and it worked `//192.168.1.5/my/folder /home/mounts/localmount  cifs user=admin,password=123,rw,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0`